# Comparing True False confusion

Tags: python

I have some confusion over testing values that are assigned False, True

To check for True value, we can simply just

```
a = True
if (a):
```

how about False?

```
a=False
if (a) <--- or should it be if (a==False), or if not a ?
```

Comment: You don't need the brackets.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty
>   sequences are false.

```
Yes: if not seq:
     if seq:

No: if len(seq)
    if not len(seq)
```

> [..]
>
> Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==.

```
Yes: if greeting:
No: if greeting == True:
Worse: if greeting is True:
```

Comment: +1 for being the most correct AND linking to the style guide.

Comment: +1 for citing the style guide. -1 for the lack of an explanation *why* this is preferable. Overall score: +/-0.

Answer (score 7):

use `not`:

```
if not a:
    ....
    # If a is the empty value like '', [], (), {}, or 0, 0.0, ..., False
    # control flow also reach here.
```

or `is False`:

```
if a is False:
    ....
```

Comment: @myusuf3 wow - I'm changing my name to Python then... easy upvotes :)

Comment: @JonClements you will need to be more original than that, also metaphorical +1 answer was good too.

Comment: @JonClements: Or you could just make a new programming language called "Jon Clements".

Comment: @MarkHildreth that's require some ego wouldn't it :)

Comment: I still don't understand "if not". say I give a the value FAlse. Then "If not a" doesn't it mean "If not False" ? I want to check that its value is False. hmmmm

Comment: @dorothy `if not False` is the same as `if (not False)`, and `not False` equals `True` for most boolean logics.

Answer (score 1):

To check for if a value is true:

```
if a:
    pass
```

To check if a value is not true:

```
if not a:
    pass
```

However, `not a:` is `True` (and true) for values other than `False`, eg. `None`, `0`, and empty containers.

If you want to check if a value is `True` or `False` (although you generally don't) try:

```
if a is True:
    pass
```

or

```
if a is False:
    pass
```

Edit: for checking if a value **is** `True` or `False` it seems you should use `if isinstance(a, bool) and a`, and `if isinstance(a, bool) and not a`

Comment: `is` is not more pythonic than `==`, it has simply different semantics

Comment: It also doesn't mean the same thing. `is` for identity, `==` for equality.

Comment: The Python Style Guide says it is more Pythonic for singletons, so I would think it would be better in the rare cases when you do want to compare to `True` or `False`, rather than just the boolean value of something.

Comment: The BDFL has explicitly said never to use `is True` or `is False`, so I'd say it's definitively not Pythonic. (His suggestion was to do explicit type-checking against `bool` if you really need to do this for some reason, because `is True` and `is False` are nearly always a sign of a bug and it's better to signal the people reading your code that you know what you're doing even though type-checking is otherwise a bad idea).

Comment: @Wooble Could you give a source for that advice from the BDFL?